# ssh executed from a script hop and X11 forwarding

Tags: bash, ssh, x11-forwarding

I am working on a small cluster with computation nodes and 2 master nodes. I can connect from my local machine to the masters or directly to the computation nodes using a ssh hop. Here is my .ssh/config on my local machine:

```
Host master0
     HostName 132.166.138.122
     User OJ239416

Host master1
     HostName 132.166.138.121
     User OJ239416

Host node*
     ProxyCommand ssh -Y master1 nc %h %p
     User OJ239416
```

Once connected to any computation or master node, I can move to another node using this script (in order to preserve environment and working directory):

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

if [[ $# != 1 ]]; then
    echo 'USAGE:'
    echo '  sssh remotename'
    exit 1
fi

DIR=$PWD

printenv | sed -e '/_=.*/ d;s/\([^=]\+\)=\(.*\)/export \1="\2"/' > $HOME/.sssh-env.txt
echo "$PWD" > $HOME/.sssh-pwd.txt
ssh -X $1
```

with this in my .bashrc:

```
if [ -f "$HOME/.sssh-env.txt" ]; then
    source $HOME/.sssh-env.txt
    cd $(cat $HOME/.sssh-pwd.txt)
    rm $HOME/.sssh-env.txt
    rm $HOME/.sssh-pwd.txt
fi
```

What does not work: if I connect from my local machine to a master node and then move to another node using my script, I got no display.

Something funny is that if I connect to a computation node from my local machine and then move to another computation node with the script, it works (but not if from a computation node I go to a master node...).

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Try adding `ForwardX11Trusted yes` to each of the master sections of the config file.

Comment: Ok it works.  I tried with `ForwardX11 yes` which does not work... Thanks!